# Java regex to extract date format out into month and year

Tags: java, regex

Hi I have the following date string format:

June-2008

July-2008

March-2010

May I enquire what is the java regex to extract out whatever the month and year value into separate string each. The delimeter here is the "-" sign

Any values from the start to the end of the "-" sign is the month, anything after the "-" sign is the year value.

The following is what I would like to achieve

```
String m = March   
String y = 2010
```

Thank all for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a regex. Use [`String#split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String[] parts = "June-2008".split("-", 2); // or .split("-")
String m = parts[0]; // "June"
String y = parts[1]; // "2008"
```

Even better, use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), and you'll have a proper [`Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) to work with:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("M-y");
Date myDate = df.parse("June-2008");
```

Comment: Thanks guys! Appreciate the various solutions given

Answer (score 0):

I want to extend the answer given by [Matt Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139010/matt-ball). If you want to split that string and willing to use other than `String#split()` you can use [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) of [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/). It has various String utility methods.

An example:

```
String strDate = "June-2008";
String[] parts = StringUtils.split(strDate, '-');
String month = parts[0]; // "June"
String year = parts[1]; // 2008
```

Also if you want to get a `java.util.Date` object then [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) may helps you. I personally prefer this api rather `java.util.Date` as it is far more rich, easy-to-use, less error-pron.

Now we can manipulate that String as:

```
String strDate = "June-2008";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMMM-yyyy");
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(strDate); // parse it
Date javaDate = dateTime.toDate(); // a java.util.Date object
int year = dateTime.getYear(); // 2008
String month = dateTime.month().getAsText(); // June
```

Hope this will help you. Thanks.